# Is it possible to view the seh chain for a particular process using C#

Tags: c#, seh

Is it possible to get the SEH chain for a particular process using C# and if so can you point me to an explanation of how to do so?

Comment: First off, surely exception handling is per-thread, not per-process. Second, I don't understand what information you're trying to get, or why you want it; can you give an example?

Comment: Are you trying to examine this on a live exception or in a binary? Big differences depending on a lot of architecture specific things.

Comment: I am trying to examine this on a live exception.